# Can I inspect variables at the breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: xcode

When I stopped at the breakpoint.

I can type something in the Xcode debug console,

In this example,

I want to inspect `self` or `thumbnail`

But it didn't support me to do that,

How could I inspect variables like in Python (pdb) or Ruby(pry)

If it's unavailable  on  Xcode, then what can I type on the console.

What is that for ? Thanks

```
- (NSURL *) thumbnailURL {
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.thumbnail class]);
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.thumbnail];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use po to print object, for example po self.thumbnail or po self

Comment: Thanks, by the way, what else can I do  on the console, jump to specific line number, or ? I'm not good at english, could you suggest some keywords let me to google, thanks so much :)

Comment: Look up breakpoints for Xcode, there are a lot of powerful things they can do more than just stop when you hit them.  In the console you can perform methods on the objects you have access to from that context and it will print out the result.  For example po self.myArray[0] will print out the first object of an array.